# Add VIA driver from command line prompt

Tags: 12.04, via, openchrome

I've tried upgrading a Windows XP environment to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I get the "low-graphics mode" screen that stalls.  I know that error is well-documented for ATI/AMD, however this machine has a VIA Technologies K8M890CE set.

Would you help me get the correct driver loaded?  I'm not scared of using the command line, so long as there are step-by-step, accurate directions.

I've tried installing openchrome, remove/install fglrx, modifying xorg.conf with no success yet...

This is a desktop PC with an AMD Athlon 64 3200+ CPU and 1 GB RAM.

Here's my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    35.456] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.5
Release Date: 2013-12-12
[    35.456] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    35.456] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
[    35.456] Current Operating System: Linux bryan-Nobilis 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:42:40 UTC 2014 i686
[    35.456] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic root=UUID=b59100ab-1c24-4c36-a9f9-3957fafaf902 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    35.456] Build Date: 06 January 2014  01:41:06PM
[    35.456] xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1~precise2 (For technical support please see h'ttp://ww'w.ubuntu.com/support') 
[    35.456] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    35.456]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    35.456] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    35.456] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 26 08:20:23 2014
[    35.692] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.935] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    35.935] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    35.935] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    35.935] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[    35.968] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    35.968] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.968] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.968] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    36.031] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    36.031]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    36.031] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    36.031]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    36.031] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    36.031]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    36.064] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    36.064]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    36.064] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    36.064]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    36.064] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    36.064] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    36.064] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    36.100] (II) Loader magic: 0xb7753620
[    36.100] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    36.100]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    36.100]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[    36.100]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[    36.100]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[    36.101] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1106:3230:105b:0c84 rev 17, Mem @ 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xdd000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
[    36.102] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    36.120] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    36.120] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    36.120] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    36.120] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    36.120] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    36.197] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    36.451] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.451]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.5.1
[    36.451]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    36.451] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    36.465] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    36.488] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.488]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[    36.488]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[    36.489] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    36.489] Loading extension GLX
[    36.489] (==) Matched openchrome as autoconfigured driver 0
[    36.489] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[    36.489] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    36.489] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    36.489] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    36.489] (II) LoadModule: "openchrome"
[    36.489] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
[    36.502] (II) Module openchrome: vendor="htt'p://ope'nchrom'e.org/"
[    36.502]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.3.1
[    36.502]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    36.502]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.502] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    36.502] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    36.505] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.505]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 2.3.2
[    36.505]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    36.505]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.505] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    36.505] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    36.510] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.510]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.8.0
[    36.510]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    36.510]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.510] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    36.510] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    36.520] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.520]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.4.3
[    36.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    36.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.520] (II) OPENCHROME: Driver for VIA Chrome chipsets: CLE266, KM400/KN400,
    K8M800/K8N800, PM800/PM880/CN400, VM800/P4M800Pro/VN800/CN700,
    CX700/VX700, K8M890/K8N890, P4M890, P4M900/VN896/CN896, VX800/VX820,
    VX855/VX875, VX900
[    36.520] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    36.520] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    36.520] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    36.521] (++) using VT number 7

[    36.521] (!!) VIA Technologies does not support this driver in any way.
[    36.521] (!!) For support, please refer to h'ttp://www.'openc'hrome.org/.
[    36.521] (!!) (openchrome 0.3.1 release)
[    36.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    36.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    36.521] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    36.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    36.521] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    36.521] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    36.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    36.524] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.524]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.0.2
[    36.524]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.524] (II) CHROME(0): VIAPreInit
[    36.524] (II) CHROME(0): VIAGetRec
[    36.524] (--) CHROME(0): Chipset: K8M890/K8N890
[    36.524] (--) CHROME(0): Chipset revision: 0
[    36.609] (EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: No such file or directory
[    36.617] (II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
[    36.617] (II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
[    36.617] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
[    36.618] (II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.618]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.1.0
[    36.618]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.618] (--) CHROME(0): Probed amount of VideoRAM = 65536 kB
[    36.618] (II) CHROME(0): VIAMapMMIO
[    36.618] (--) CHROME(0): mapping MMIO @ 0xdd000000 with size 0xd000
[    36.618] (--) CHROME(0): mapping BitBlt MMIO @ 0xdd200000 with size 0x200000
[    36.618] (II) CHROME(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0
[    36.618] (II) CHROME(0): VIAMapFB
[    36.618] (--) CHROME(0): mapping framebuffer @ 0xc0000000 with size 0x4000000
[    36.619] (--) CHROME(0): Frame buffer start: 0xb2a97000, free start: 0x0 end: 0x4000000
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): RGB weight 888
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): VIASetupDefaultOptions - Setting up default chipset options.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Shadow framebuffer is disabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Hardware acceleration is enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Using EXA acceleration architecture.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): EXA composite acceleration disabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): EXA scratch area size is 4096 kB.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Using hardware two-color cursors and software full-color cursors.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): GPU virtual command queue will be enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): DRI IRQ will be enabled if DRI is enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): AGP DMA will be disabled if DRI is enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): PCI DMA will not be used for XV image transfer if DRI is enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Will not enable VBE modes.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): VBE VGA register save & restore will not be used
    if VBE modes are enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Xv Bandwidth check is enabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Will not impose a limit on video RAM reserved for DRI.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Will try to allocate 32768 kB of AGP memory.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): TV dotCrawl is disabled.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): TV deflicker is set to 0.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV type is set.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV output signal type is set.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): No default TV output port is set.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Will not print VGA registers.
[    36.619] (==) CHROME(0): Will not scan I2C buses.
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): ...Finished parsing config file options.
[    36.619] (--) CHROME(0): Detected Foxconn K8M890M2MA-RS2H. Card-Ids (105B| C84)
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): Detected MemClk 7
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): ViaGetMemoryBandwidth. Memory type: 7
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): Detected TV standard: NTSC.
[    36.619] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    36.619] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    36.619] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    36.619] (II) Loading sub module "i2c"
[    36.619] (II) LoadModule: "i2c"
[    36.619] (II) Module "i2c" already built-in
[    36.619] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CInit
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CBus1Init
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 1" initialized.
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2cBus2Init
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 2" initialized.
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): ViaI2CBus3Init
[    36.636] (II) CHROME(0): I2C bus "I2C bus 3" initialized.
[    36.637] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    36.637] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    36.637] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    36.637] (II) CHROME(0): ViaOutputsDetect
[    36.637] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS-0 : Digital output bus width is 12 bits.
[    36.637] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS-0 : DVI Center is disabled.
[    36.637] (==) CHROME(0): LVDS Panel will not be forced.
[    36.637] (==) CHROME(0): Panel size is not selected from config file.
[    36.637] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[    36.638] (II) CHROME(0): I2C device "I2C bus 1:ddc2" registered at address 0xA0.
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Manufacturer: ACR  Model: 1a5  Serial#: 353434227
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Year: 2011  Week: 51
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Sync:  Separate
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 44  vert.: 25
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): DPMS capabilities: Off; RGB/Color Display
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.312 whiteY: 0.329
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Supported established timings:
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 640x480@67Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 640x480@72Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 800x600@56Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 800x600@72Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 832x624@75Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): 1152x864@75Hz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Supported standard timings:
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): #3: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): clock: 108.0 MHz   Image Size:  443 x 249 mm
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): h_active: 1600  h_sync: 1624  h_sync_end 1704 h_blank_end 1800 h_border: 0
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): v_active: 900  v_sync: 901  v_sync_end 904 v_blanking: 1000 v_border: 0
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 80 kHz, PixClock max 165 MHz
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Serial No: LNY080034225
[    36.690] (II) CHROME(0): Monitor name: Acer S201HL
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): EDID (in hex):
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    00ffffffffffff000472a50173fa1015
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    33150103682c19782aee91a3544c9926
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    0f5054bfee80714f81c08100a9c00101
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    010101010101302a40c8608464301850
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    1300bbf91000001e000000fd00324c1e
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    5010000a202020202020000000ff004c
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    4e593038303033343232350a000000fc
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0):    00416365722053323031484c0a200070
[    36.691] (--) CHROME(0): DDC pI2CBus1 detected a CRT
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): EDID vendor "ACR", prod id 421
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  108.00  1600 1624 1704 1800  900 901 904 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz eP)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.8   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 connected
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    36.691] (II) CHROME(0): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1600x900
[    36.692] (II) CHROME(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    36.692] (==) CHROME(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    36.692] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    36.692] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    36.692] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    36.707] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.707]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[    36.707]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    36.707] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[    36.707] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[    36.707] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[    36.719] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.719]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 2.6.0
[    36.719]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    36.719] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    36.719] (II) Unloading vesa
[    36.719] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    36.719] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    36.719] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    36.719] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    36.719] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    36.719] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    36.719] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    36.720] (II) CHROME(0): VIAScreenInit
[    36.720] (II) CHROME(0): Frame Buffer From (0,0) To (1600,10485)
[    36.720] (II) CHROME(0): Using 9585 lines for offscreen memory.
[    36.720] 5760000 bytes of Linear memory allocated at 57e400, handle 3080119136
[    36.720] 262144 bytes of Linear memory allocated at afc800, handle 3080110640
[    36.720] 32 bytes of Linear memory allocated at b3c900, handle 3080118992
[    36.720] 32 bytes of Linear memory allocated at b3c980, handle 3080121432
[    36.720] (II) CHROME(0): - Visuals set up
[    36.722] (II) CHROME(0): - B & W
[    36.723] (II) CHROME(0): [EXA] Disabling EXA accelerated composite.
[    36.723] (**) CHROME(0): Option "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy"
[    36.723] (II) EXA(0): Offscreen pixmap area of 61348864 bytes
[    36.723] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[    36.723] (II)         Solid
[    36.723] (II)         Copy
[    36.723] (II) CHROME(0): [EXA] Enabled EXA acceleration.
```

Note in particular the errors

```
[    36.521] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
...
[    36.609] (EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: No such file or directory
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/dri/`:

```
Cannot access /dev/dri/ : No such file or directory
```

Here's my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device" Identifier "Configured Video Device" Driver "openchrome" EndSection

Section "Monitor Identifier "Configured Monitor" VendorName "Acer" ModelName "S201HL" HorizSync 30.0 - 53.0 VertRefresh 50.0 - 60.0 EndSection Section "Module" Load "dri" EndSection

Section "Screen" Identifier "Default Screen" Monitor "Configured Monitor" Device "Configured Video Device" EndSection
```

Comment: The partial Ubuntu install's not recognizing the USB media folder yet.  I'll keep researching this issue...

Comment: Hi Malte, it is a laptop, and I've tried to update the post with the cpuinfo and meminfo.  thanks, Bryan.

Comment: Hi Malte, you're right, the three lines is not how it looks in reality.  I did add the quote marks to "Monitor ; did a re-start and nothing changed.  I will try removing the xorg.conf.  Today, I'm getting a purple screen with Ubuntu and four or five dots below Ubuntu.  That's a step up from the "low-graphics mode" stall screen at least.  Thanks!  Bryan

Comment: Removing the xorg.conf as you suggested and rebooting didn't solve it.  The two errors I see in the Xorg.0 file:

Comment: [    36.521] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    36.609] (EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes.  Cannot access /dev/dri/ : No such file or directory

Comment: Earlier, I said laptop, this is actually desktop.  Sorry for mis-typing if that led you astray...

Comment: In addition, I've also checked the disk for errors and the install dvd looks good.  I'm wondering if I ought to try a newer or older version of ubuntu on this machine.

Comment: Well, it looks like there is some kind of problem with the openchrome module. Maybe it's not correctly loaded, or not correctly installed, or maybe somehow it doesn't recognize your card properly. It's hard to tell, especially without the machine at hand to do some trying around. If I were you, I would google for those errors, namely `(EE) CHROME(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device` (don't put the exact bus id in the Google search), and `(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory`. You will find some interesting suggestions. If I have time I may help look into it :)

Comment: If nothing helps, though, a newer version of Ubuntu (13.10 or in a month or so 14.04) may also be a good thing to try. They will probably have newer driver versions which may work better. You could just try a newer Ubuntu from the live CD and see if you get decent graphics. If it works on the live CD, it will work on an installed system and it'll be worth installing that.

Comment: Could you post the output of `lsmod | grep openchrome`? If there is no output then the module is not loaded. In that case try `sudo modprobe openchrome` to load the module and if that works then `sudo service lightdm restart` to restart the X server. Otherwise post the output. In thase case the module is loaded, and is probably having problems recognizing your card.